# Dynamic Programming for Minimum Path Sum

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am not understanding how to exactly use dynamic programming for the Minimum Path Sum Problem. The problem statement is as follows.

```
Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from 
top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers 
along its path.
Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.
```

Here is the code i tried using just recursion.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"
#include "cmath"
#include "algorithm"
using namespace std;
class Solution {
 public:
int s = INT_MAX;
int helper(int sum, vector<vector<int>> &grid, int i, int j) {
    if (i == grid.size() - 1 && j == grid[0].size() - 1) {
        return s = min(s, sum + grid[i][j]);
    }
    if (i >= grid.size() || j >= grid[0].size()) {
        return sum;
    }
return min(helper(sum + grid[i][j], grid, i + 1, j) + helper(sum + grid[i][j], grid, i, j + 1), s);

}
int minPathSum(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
    return helper(0, grid, 0, 0);
}
};

int main()
{
vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };
vector<vector<int>> r;
r.push_back(v);
v = { 4,5,6 };
r.push_back(v);
v = { 7,8,9 };
r.push_back(v);
v = { 1,2,3 };
r.push_back(v);
Solution s;
cout<<s.minPathSum(r);
return 0;
}
```

And here is a code where i tried using Dynamic programming where I am storing the least sum at a given index `[i,j]` and returning it, but its not being of much help, the Online Coding Judge says "Time Limit Exceeded" 
Can you please help me improve the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"
#include "cmath"
#include "algorithm"
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
int s = INT_MAX;
int helper(int sum, vector<vector<int>> &grid, int i, int j,vector<vector<int>> &memoize) {
    if (i == grid.size() - 1 && j == grid[0].size() - 1) {
        return s = min(s, sum + grid[i][j]);
    }
    if (i >= grid.size() || j >= grid[0].size()) {
        return sum;
    }
    if (sum + grid[i][j] < memoize[i][j])
        memoize[i][j] = sum + grid[i][j];
    else
        return memoize[i][j];

    return min(helper(sum + grid[i][j], grid, i + 1, j,memoize) + helper(sum + grid[i][j], grid, i, j + 1,memoize), s);
}
int minPathSum(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
    vector<vector<int>> memoize(grid.size(), vector<int>(grid[0].size(), INT_MAX));
    return helper(0, grid, 0, 0,memoize);
}
};
  int main()
 {
vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };
vector<vector<int>> r;
r.push_back(v);
v = { 4,5,6 };
r.push_back(v);
v = { 7,8,9 };
r.push_back(v);
v = { 1,2,3 };
r.push_back(v);
Solution s;
cout<<s.minPathSum(r);
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: "Time Limit Exceeded" means you either have a very inefficient algorithm (unlikely, here) - or you have an infinite loop / infinite recursion.  Consider your exit conditions.

Comment: This code runs in time on my laptop. Time limits exceeds only for the last test case

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
This would include a trace of execution showing inefficiencies in the case that's timing out.  What does your DP matrix hold?  Where is the time getting spent?  You have debugging print statements or some debugger output to show?

Comment: It could exit in some cases but not all.  Debug the final test case on your laptop and watch where it gets stuck.